# Sort graph nodes by density

Tags: algorithms, graphs, sorting, graph-traversal

Imagine villages (or Internet Routers) scattered all over the world (or World Wide Web) connected by roads or shipping lanes (or Cables). All villages (**nodes**) has the same amount of villagers which visit some other villages (their intentions are undefined, so it's basically random) through shortest paths over the roads (**edges**). What is the way to sort villages by amount of travelers passed through it? *Without forcing people to actually travel since we need to build hotels to make their journeys comfortable.*

I think the technical specification of the problem can be like this:
Cyclic connected undirected graph. Every node in a graph has T value initially zero. Suppose there is a traversal via shortest path between every two nodes which increases every node's T value it passes through by 1 / N where N is amount of shortest paths between these nodes.

What is an algorithm to sort nodes by T without an actual traversing (faster than that)?

P.S. If there are two shortest paths, so it's like villager chooses to pass through random one (as defined as **1/N** since we need to prepare hotels for approximate amount of visitors).

Comment: You can choose a large number, say $N\log N$, of pairs of nodes, and compute the shortest paths, say using a dedicated algorithm like http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1134.pdf. You will get a good estimate of the densities, which you can use to calculate the approximate order.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, Thank you. So it basically means we can't decide hotels sizes without actually traveling ...

Comment: Maybe you can. There is always the chance that there is some nifty formula that gives you exactly the $T$ scores.

Comment: You previously posted a version of this question, got a bunch of comments, and deleted the previous version and posted this new version -- but without addressing the comments (many of those comments still apply here).  As Gilles says: What do you mean by “a traverse”? A traversal?  [...]  You mention modifying T values, do you mean a transformation of the graph?

Comment: Also: I encourage you to edit the question to clarify what you mean. For instance: What is a T value? What is a "traverse"? (as Gilles accurately points out, that is unclear). What does it mean for a traverse to modify the T values? What is an "amount of shortest paths", and between which nodes? What do you mean by "an actual traversing" -- and how fast does it have to be, to be faster than that? What research have you done, and what are your thoughts?

Comment: Finally: undefined is not the same as random.  If you are assuming that each traveller's destination is random, with what distribution?  Uniform distribution on all villages?  If there's a traveller in village X who wants to visit village Y, and there are multiple shortest paths from X to Y, what happens then?  How do you anticipate breaking ties?  (Does the villager choose uniformly at random among all such shortest paths?)  Please edit the question to specify these aspects more carefully.

Comment: @D.W. that question was closed by you and 2 other admins after a request to "modify" it which I did in an hour it was issued, so it wasn't me who deleted the question, please be more accurate. Question edited to have "traversal", sorry for grammar. **T** is the field value of every node of the graph, so no - it is not a transformation. "amount of shortest paths" is between T's node and every other node in the graph.

Comment: @D.W, mathematical specification of the task is clear on all the question you ask here: when you speak about "randomness, distribution, undefined, etc." you ignore **1/N** meaning. For example, if there is a single shortest path between two nodes, then **T** value is just increased by 1 for every node it passes through, if 2 paths, so every node of these paths takes +0.5 for it's **T** value. etc. If you unable to understand the specification, please read the real-life-alike one and pretend you're an adequate person trying to solve human-related problems, but please don't close the question.

Comment: @D.W. originally I didn't had such specification in my previous question, you're right. You requested to perform it, so I did in an hour, but two days later you closed the question without any comment, so now I cannot both comment or edit it. Now I provided both mathematical (in a common graph notation) and real-life specifications so such problems shouldn't arise. All your questions (even if mathematical is unclear) can be easily took from real-life one. If you feel uncomfortable about reviewing the problem which cannot be solved, or wrong definition, please refer this: https://goo.gl/aORABg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26785/discussion-between-slav-and-d-w).

Comment: @Slav, sorry about the frustration.  The question was put on hold while waiting for you to edit it.  However, after the question spent 7 days on hold without edits that responded to the comments, it was automatically deleted.  Our moderator Gilles undeleted the post to give you some extra time to edit it, but I'm not sure why it was deleted again so rapidly.  Sorry for the confusion.  (To be clear, I voted to put it on hold.  I did not vote to delete, and one of the moderators did try to undelete it.)

Comment: We do have a policy of putting questions on hold if the community cannot understand the question, so they can be clarified -- see our [help] for more about how this site works.  I hear that you are frustrated, but at the same time, remember that something that seems entirely clear to you is not necessarily clear to others.  If others are giving you feedback that some aspect is not clear, one way to address this is to further edit the question to add further clarifications/mathematical definitions/etc.  Alternatively, you can hope that I'm an outlier and everyone else finds it clear.